# Frequency modulation without amplitude modulation in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, frequency, web-audio-api

I'm working in the WebAudio API to try and make an array of simple, frequency-modulated signal, but when I modulate it, there is also some amplitude modulation introduced (beating?). What I need is a pure webAudio FM modulated signal with **no** AM interference generated. What I have *sounds* right, but when I hook it up to my oscilloscope, I can see the Amplitude Modulations. Relevant code is below for one of the oscillators in the array - any ideas or suggestions? Thank you in advance!

```
    oscMod[i] = audioCtx.createOscillator();
    gainMod[i] = audioCtx.createGain();
    oscCarrier[i] = audioCtx.createOscillator();
    gainOsc[i] = audioCtx.createGain();
    
    oscCarrier[i].frequency.value = initialHz;
    oscMod[i].frequency.value = 6;//rate of FM modulation
    gainMod[i].gain.value = 0; //10% modulation
    gainOsc[i].gain.value = 0;
    
    oscMod[i].connect(gainMod[i]);
    gainMod[i].connect(oscCarrier[i].frequency);
    oscCarrier[i].connect(gainOsc[i]);
    gainOsc[i].connect(audioCtx.destination)

//10% modulation of the carrier frequency
    gainMod[channel].gain.setValueAtTime(oscCarrier[channel].frequency.value * .1, start)
    gainOsc[channel].gain.setValueAtTime(0, start);
    gainOsc[channel].gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(amp, start + rampTime)
```

Image of oscilloscope output:
[image: Oscilloscope output]

Comment: Not seeing anywhere here.  Can you share snapshots of your oscilliscope?  Is the modulation constant (can you hack it and scale down by a fudge factor)?

Comment: @neonwatty updated the post with an image of the oscilloscope output